# How to format windows using bios without removing ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bios, format

I have two OS in my PC, windows 10 and ubuntu 16.4. I want to update windows by formatting it with a new version using BIOS. How to do this without removing ubuntu.Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't know of any BIOS software which can format partitions. You will need to use a Windows installation disc, and then use Ubuntu Live to restore Grub. You will need to be very careful about the options during installation, and of course back up the whole disc before you start.

Comment: If your trying to update your BIOS, then there is no need to format windows.  Windows and BIOS are 2 completely different things.

Comment: Are you trying to update the BIOS or Windows? You're wording is a bit confusing

Comment: No I'm trying to delete windows and reinstall it with new version using bios which means low level formatting and also trying to keep ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are no options for the user to format a hard drive in the BIOS.

Instead of looking for hard ways to do things do the normal simple way.

1. Install gparted on ubuntu
2. launch it
3. delete the windows partition
4. Create a new ntfs partition in its place.
5. Click Apply
6. boot from the Windows Installation Media
7. Select the blank partition and install windows

Comment: Also then you have to repair grub. As Windows replaces grub with it's own bootloader.